# YOLO V2 with Kinect v2 and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, kinect, yolo

all

I am using YOLO v2 for object recognition, when I run the following code

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/voc.data cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg tiny-yolo-voc.weights
```

I get video stream from the webcam, but I want to get the video stream from the camera Kinect v2. The Yolo V2 get the video stream from `cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(cam_index);` in the file `demo.c` in darknet and the kinect v2 get the rgb videos stream from the `libfreenect2::Frame *rgb = frames[libfreenect2::Frame::Color];//BGRA format` in libfreenct2

I want to use kinect v2 and Yolo v2 for object detection !!!!! Any one can give me help ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to take every frame from the kinect and convert it to a MAT so you can send it to yolo, you can use opencv to do this, python will do it pretty easily as you just need to do

rgbMat = KinectFrame

i dont know C but has to be similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
 It extracts both the color and depth stream.

```
kinect = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime(PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Color)
kinectD = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime(PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Depth)

while True:
    stime = time.time()
    if kinect.has_new_color_frame():
        frame = kinect.get_last_color_frame()
        frame = np.reshape(frame, (1080, 1920, 4))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=.5, fy=.5)
        #frameC = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

        frameD = kinectD.get_last_depth_frame()
        frameDepth = kinectD._depth_frame_data
        frameD = frameD.astype(np.uint8)
        frameD = np.reshape(frameD,(424, 512))
        frameD = cv2.cvtColor(frameD, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Here is a video of a python program that uses pykinect, yolo 2 and extracts the depth also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyKOIxOOwYk
the video is not the best but there is a link to the github repository with the code.